# Creating a upload form in EE

Tags: add-on, ee

Trying to create a simple form that allows a visitor to submit a GPX file and basic contact info.
Is there a simple way to do this without using a plugin?

All I find is this - I'm not sure it's still supported?
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/file-uploading.html
Thanks in advance.
S

Answer (score 2):

The Channel Form module lets you add front end submissions, information is stored as regular channel entries
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/overview.html